# EF Code First relation 0/1 to 0/1 with various parents

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have some problems with EF CodeFirst and relations 0/1 to 0/1. I have 3 "tables" that contains another, and this is optional.

It's similar to:

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{  
    [DataMember, Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int? IdD
    [ForeignKey("idD")]
    public virtual D D {get; set;}
} 
[DataContract] 
public class B
{  
    [DataMember, Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int? IdD
    [ForeignKey("idD")]
    public virtual D D {get; set;}
}
[DataContract]
public class C
{  
    [DataMember, Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int? IdD
    [ForeignKey("idD")]
    public virtual D D {get; set;}
}    
[DataContract]
public class D
{
    [DataMember, Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to made the migration, appears the error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'XXXXXX' and 'XXXXXX'. 
The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship 
fluent API or data annotations.
```

I try with DataAnnotations and with Fluent API and appears the same error. On Fluent API I try:

with A, B or C class

```
        this.HasOptional(casv => casv.D)
            .WithOptionalDependent(e => e.A)//I try with denendent and Principal
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdD")) // I try without this
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think it's better looking than your code:

```
this.HasOptional(casv => casv.D)
    .WithOptionalDependent(e => e.A)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdD"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Thank's but on question appears this code, please you don't have  copy&paste

Comment: This is not an answer, and is quite subjective. I like his formatting better than yours since it's easier to read..

Comment: that means that your screen is too small or your visual radius its limited, sorry to hear that, buy a new screen or a new pair of eyes. ^^

Comment: @Anonymous Slightly ironic that your answer stating your opinion about code looking "awful" included code that was not properly formatted... ;)